# can not load clamav-extension

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, clamav

I try to use the clamav-extension by following [these steps](http://phpmaster.com/zf-clamav/).
There weren't any errors, but after restarting apache, no clam-extension is loaded.

```
php -v
```

returns no errors.
I've set the extension_dir in php.ini and clamav.so is in there.

```
extension=clamav.so
```

is also set.
ClamAV itself is installed and works. Where could I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried verifying its installed with something like `php -i | grep clam` ?

Does the clam.so have the correct permissions?

For what it's worth Sebastiaan Stock in the comments of the steps you posted recommended not to run clamav as an extension and instead run it as a daemon to reduce memory.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV#Run_ClamAV_as_a_Daemon